# Syntax highlighting for PHP files without PHP tags in Zend Studio

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, zend-studio

I'm working on a PHP framework that doesn't require included file to start with a open PHP tag (`<?php`), in fact it will fail if a file does include one of these tags. Is there a way to tell Zend Studio to treat any PHP file as if it is in a PHP block by default so that I can have syntax highlighting and code completion?

Comment: How are you doing that in the first place? Tell me you're not using `eval()` :)

Comment: Actually eval should be fairly safe in this case since I'm parsing known code and there's nothing dynamic in there, so you'd need to be able to edit the server's PHP files to do any injections, in which case just running the app normally would be unsafe. In any case, I'm using eval only for unit testing, otherwise the files are cached as actual PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

As silly as this might sound, why not just add the opening tags during editing and then remove them/comment them out for production?  Either that, or you'd probably have to manually change the syntax recognition packages, which'd be a real pain...